# Trigger which counts datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Hello for hobby purposes i am trying to create a C# application with a MS SQL Server database which reassembles a hotel system. I am now trying to create a SQL trigger which calculates a datedifference. A reservation may not be longer than 6 weeks(42 days). However, my trigger goes off even when placing reservations which have a datedifference lower than 42 days, even if the difference is 1 day. so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My trigger:

```
create trigger trigger_reservation
on reservation
after update, insert
as
if exists
(
select reservationid, DATEDIFF(dd,Startdate,Enddate)
from reservation
group by reservationid, enddate, startdate
having DATEDIFF(dd,Startdate,Enddate) > 42
)
begin
    raiserror('Error: Reservation may not be longer than 6 weeks',16, 1)
    rollback transaction
end
```

Comment: Surely your trigger is checking the ENTIRE table rather than just the row you are inserting?  If you already have a reservation greater than 42 days in the data table then the trigger will always fire.

Comment: You are right, there are indeed some reservations which are longer than 42 days(random generated data). How would I go with fixing this?

Comment: Basically you need to know about the "special" tables that you have access to in a trigger, the one you want here being "inserted".  I see that peterm has updated his answer, and that should work exactly as you require...

Comment: With update and insert statement you can modify more than one row at the time. your trigger is trigger once for all rows which are updated. when one row fails the check none is inserted/updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there a way for the trigger to only check newly inserted rows?

Answer (score 3):

Triggers are expensive to run and maintain. This type of check can be accomplished by a simple `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation (
  reservationid INT,
  startdate DATE,
  enddate DATE,
  -- ...
  CONSTRAINT reservation_dates_ck 
    CHECK(DATEDIFF(dd, startdate, enddate) < 43)
)
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=16b649c14074a5474149449469f1ff01) demo

And here's how you go about doing it with a trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_reservation
ON reservation AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM inserted
     WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, startdate, enddate) > 42
  )  
  BEGIN  
    RAISERROR ('Error: Reservation may not be longer than 6 weeks', 16, 1);  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
  RETURN   
END;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=483a4d4b862c4d9a1caca513833e6ed8) demo

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about checks but for testing purposes I really want it to be a trigger.

Comment: The check constraint is the best way to go about this. Using a trigger here is sort of like using a cursor when a set based solution is available.

Comment: @SeanLange Exactly my point but the OP wants to learn triggers which is absolutely fine.

Comment: Heh I knew it was your point. I was providing a second opinion that is the same. :D